# ASP.Net Core 2.2 Logging

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

I create a brand new ASP.Net Core MVC site in Visual Studio 2017.

The generated appsettings.json specifies a default logging level of "Warning".

When I run the site, I still get "Information" level logging on the console. I would expect to see only warnings and above.

Is this supposed to work straight out of the box, or do I need to add something?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! It turns out my appsettings.json does NOT specify a level of "Warning".

At least, it does, but drill down and the appsetting.Development.json specifies "Debug". And I was running in development mode.

Personally, I'd have thought best practice would be to put settings that are different in both the Development and Production files, rather than allowing one to override the other.

Comment: you don't need to run appsettings.json in production, you can instead have appsettings.production.json and the default file will have only common setup. Check my answer for details.

Comment: I get that you can have a production version. I just think it's potentially confusing that the generated project doesn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

You get an override from `appsettings.development.json`

This is how `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` sets things up.

Check code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L171).

```
 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

You are free to override this registrations as you want. But default that environment file wins over ordinary `appsettings.json`. But in the end it's up to you how you want to configure it. But I think it's quite sensible default.

Comment: Not sure this is a solution to the original question.

Comment: The author found that it was development config that was overriding, so this is the explanation on why this is happening, I can extend the answer